# Simultaneous spatial SQL queries successively slower

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, spatial

I have a fairly simple spatial query that completes in around 1 second normally. As part of my load testing I'm sending the query from 10 different threads, and most of the ten take a lot longer, up to 30 seconds on occasion.  If I add more threads it goes up to a few minutes. 
The wait type I'm seeing is async_network_io but there's not a super large amount of data being returned and SQL Sentry says my server is only using 0.2% of its network pipe.  My workstation's pipe never spikes above 15%.  Can somebody explain to me what I can do to get the queries to all execute in a second (up to a reasonable number of threads)?

Here's an example:

```
SELECT "Lon","Lat","ParcelID","ParcelPolygon".STAsBinary() as "ParcelPolygon" 
FROM "ParcelData" WITH(INDEX("IX_ParcelData_SpatialHigh")) 
WHERE  "ParcelPolygon".Filter(geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((-149.61737394332886 61.52266425353893,
 -149.61737394332886 61.525344727039275, -149.61175203323364 61.525344727039275, -149.61175203323364
 61.52266425353893, -149.61737394332886 61.52266425353893))', 4326)) = 1
```

Comment: *I have a fairly simple spatial query that completes in around 1 second normally* Does your query `SELECT` data or `UPDATE` it too? Not everything can be done concurrently.

Comment: I added an example, it's just a select. I will try a few different zoom levels (i.e. polygon sizes) to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: `async_network_io` often indicates that the process that's executing the query isn't able to consume the data as rapidly as SQL Server can provide it. Have you run the same query in SSMS?

Comment: Yes, it's always around 1 second in SSMS. Does that tell me something?

Comment: I verified that the larger the result set the more successive queries slow down.

Comment: I tried running the multithreaded test from the SQL server itself, but the results are the same even though there is no network involved. I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem really was that SQL Server was trying to return data faster than the application could handle it.  I found a couple different ways to mitigate the problem.

1. Use the Reduce() function on the geometry column. I had to use a factor of .00003 in order for the polygons to remain intact but that still gave a 6x decrease in dataset size.
2. Turn off the map layer by default at higher zoom levels. A lower zoom level means a smaller dataset.

Together those solutions made a big difference, but I still see delays with 20+ users simultaneously using the map layer.

Comment: Turns out the delays with 20+ users were due to Java memory config issues within Geoserver.